# Moving nodes between scenes

Tags: node-editor

1. How to move a node group from one scene to another?
2. Is it possible to move a shader node tree from one scene to another, or for that I have to merge the nodes in a group?
   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new scene with the same nodes, click on 'plus' icon and choose the *Link Object Data* option.
[image]

If you have two different scenes, you can copy the nodes from one to another. Select them and copy with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then paste to the new scene.
[image]

In every scene you have the access to the all created material nodes. Just click on material browser and choose the desired material.
[image]